# wcf .net4 dictionary containing dictionaries

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, dictionary, known-types

I am trying to return an array of `dictionary <string, object>` where the object may contain a basic type such as int, bool, etc or it could contain another array of `dictionary<string, object>`

Though I can get it serialize fine, it will not deserialize if there is a dictionary within the dictionary.

I get the following error:

```
Error in line 1 position 543. Element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:Value' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:ArrayOfArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add the type corresponding to 'ArrayOfArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
```

the class:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "CISICPD")]
[KnownType(typeof(Dictionary<string,object>))]
public class TestResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string,object>[] Results;
}
```

function:

```
public TestResponse test(string test1, string test2)
    {
        TestResponse r = new TestResponse();
        r.Results = new Dictionary<string, object>[1];
        r.Results[0] = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        r.Results[0].Add("field1", 26);
        Dictionary<string, object>[] d = new Dictionary<string, object>[1];
        d[0] = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        d[0].Add("inner", 28);
        r.Results[0].Add("dictionary", d);
        return r;
    }
```

running this gives the error message but i think ive got the correct knowntype?

```
CISICPD.CPDClient t = new CISICPD.CPDClient();
CISICPD.TestResponse response = t.test("dgdf", "dfsdfd");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add the following property to your datacontract class.

```
[DataMember]
public object UsedForKnownTypeSerializationObject;
```

So now the generated proxy contains the Knowtypes you set on the datacontract. I had the same problem and this is the only solution I came up with. If you don't at the a property of type Object to you DataContract class, the generated proxy doesn't contain the declared knowtypes

For example:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(List<String>))]
public class Foo
{
    [DataMember]
    public String FooName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public IDictionary<String, Object> Inputs { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    private Object UsedForKnownTypeSerializationObject{ get; set; }

}
```

It's not as pretty because you end up with a dummy property which doesn't have any functional implementation. But then again I don't have another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the known types on TestResponse:

```
[KnownType(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>[]))]
```

Because "d" is an array of Dictionary objects in the test method and you're storing that as a value in Results, the type needs to be added to the known types.

Check out the "Collections and Known Types" section of this link for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx

Basically any type that you're going to be storing in Results as an object will need to have a KnownType added.

Comment: I'm still getting the exact same message having made that change and updated the service reference

Comment: ok ive found what the issue is - the knowntype attribute is being ignored. the reference.cs file generated by adding/updating a service reference doesnt have the knowntype for class testresponse. if I add it in the code then works fine. so why would it ignore the knowntype when generating the reference.cs file?

Comment: I don't normally use Service References, so I'm not sure why the KnownType attribute isn't being generated, but it seems to only happen when using the DataContractSerializer.  If you try running svcutil manually from the command line and specify the XmlSerializer, it will generate a proxy with the correct known types: "svcutil YourServiceURL /serializer:XmlSerializer /noConfig"

Comment: that generated a cs file with no knowntypes at all and also seemed to be missing other bits as well